# Carácter delimitador de entrada de enteros (C++)

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda, si tengo una entrada "1+2+3+4+5", y quiero guardarlos en un vector de enteros, ¿qué puedo hacer para guardarlos delimitándose por cada signo "+"? Es decir, que el vector se llene con 1 2 3 4 5.

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numero;
    vector<int> valores;

    while (cin >> numero)
    {
        valores.push_back(numero);
    }
int s=valores.size();
sort(valores.begin(),valores.end());
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        if(i==s-1){
            cout << valores[i];
        }else{
        cout << valores[i] << "+";
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creo que puedes consumir el número y luego lo otro lo vas desechando, tal que int num; char tmp; while(cin>>num) {cout << num; cin>>tmp} Disculpa el formato pero estoy desde el móvil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como ha dicho [WolfyLPDC](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/car%c3%a1cter-delimitador-de-entrada-de-enteros-c#comment369623_197047https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/car%c3%a1cter-delimitador-de-entrada-de-enteros-c#comment369623_197047) en los comentarios, puedes leer directamente de la consola:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int numero;
    while (std::cin >> numero)
    {
        std::cout << "Numero leido: " << numero << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si ejecutas el código anterior poniendo como datos de entrada `"1+2+3+4+5"` obtendrás como salida:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```

Para guardarlo en un vector, simplemente ve añadiendo valores a mediad que los obtienes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int numero;
    std::vector<int> valores;

    while (std::cin >> numero)
    {
        valores.push_back(numero);
    }

    for (const auto &valor : valores)
    {
        std::cout << "Numero leido: " << valor << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra la misma salida que el primer ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¿pero cómo lo puedo guardar en un vector? Intenté usando una variable auxiliar y rellenar el vector con push_back, pero no puedo cerrar el ciclo, debido a que no puedo usar size para determinar el largo del int, y si uso string, puedo tomarlo con getline, pero tengo problemas al hacer atoi, ya que no es char, y si uso char, y si los guardo en un vector con string no puedo usar getline, además tengo errores al usar un for con atoi a cada uno de los sectores del mismo. He intentado de todas las formas que se me ocurren, pero no he tenido éxito.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, pero continúo sin poder salir del while terminando con un número y no con un símbolo. Porque necesito trabajar con el vector, pero mi entrada siempre será comenzando con un número y terminando con otro, delimitando el valor que se le dará a cada espacio del vector con un "+". Por lo que el hecho de terminar con un número no me deja salir del ciclo, y no sé cómo salir de él.Todo funciona bien, sólo estoy teniendo ese problema. Edito la pregunta y adjunto el código.

Comment: Hola @jignacio no veo en ninguna parte de tu pregunta inicial el requerimiento de "*salir del while terminando con un número y no con un símbolo*" por lo que mi respuesta no incluye ese detalle. Mientras el programa se encuentre con una petición de entrada de datos, pedirá datos al usuario.